# AVPlayerLayer video "overspilled" when videoGravity set to AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill

Tags: objective-c, ios, avplayer

I've set up the custom UIView with AVPlayerLayer as suggested on the Apple Developer Library. Everything works fine, but when I set the videoGravity of the AVPlayerLayer to AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill, it seems that the parts that are outside of the frame are visible as well. It appears to have an alpha on it too.

I tried setting masksToBounds = YES but it didn't seem to solve the problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

You should select the checkbox "Clip subviews" of your AVPlayerLayerView in Xcode. Or you need to set the property accordingly to YES.

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same issue, and fix it by switch to
AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect. 
AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect ensure the preview layer resize inside your frame bounds.